# adding web contents to oracle forms developer 10g

Tags: jquery, oracle, applet, oracleforms

i  want to add news tricker in the header of form(build using oracle forms developer 10g)
2. adding a menu  that each submenu take me to page that   display some text contents(like introduction about a company for example).
what is the best way to add  some web contents to a page that is build using oracle forms developer 10g?
is it it possible to add a jquery pluging( for news tricker)  to oracle form?

thanks You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can integrate JavaScript in Oracle Forms, including JQuery.  Oracle has a tutorial for this on its site.  The published examples are for Forms 11g, but you can probably backport them  to 10g with a bit of effort.  [Check it out](http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/forms/11g/jsinteg/formsjsinteg/setup.htm).